# Remove sound output device 2019 - SB230

Tags: macos, audio, catalina

I'm not a MBP expert, but I installed something a while ago that was supposed to function as an EQ but didn't work well. After removal, that SB230 sound output device still haunts me.

Can anyone assist? System profile below:

```
Devices:

        Built-in Microphone:

          Default Input Device: Yes
          Input Channels: 2
          Manufacturer: Apple Inc.
          Current SampleRate: 44100
          Transport: Built-in
          Input Source: Internal Microphone

        Built-in Output:

          Default Output Device: Yes
          Default System Output Device: Yes
          Manufacturer: Apple Inc.
          Output Channels: 2
          Current SampleRate: 44100
          Transport: Built-in
          Output Source: Internal Speakers

        DisplayPort:

          Manufacturer: Apple Inc.
          Output Channels: 2
          Current SampleRate: 48000
          Transport: DisplayPort
          Output Source: SB230
```

Comment: Googling 'SB230' gives nothing relevant. Can you add more info as to what precisely you installed?

Comment: Hi @Tetsujin i think it was eqMac. Is there a way I can see a log of program install/removal to help narrow it down? The problem is that the sound output defaults to that, causing no sound output from speakers.